# What happens if I don't call free_irq() in the driver's exit function?

Tags: kernel, driver, interrupt, kernel-module, interrupt-handling

So, I wrote a basic char driver with IRQ_NO 1 for keyboard and registered a shared handler function for it. In this exit function I don't free the handler using free_irq(). In the dmesg logs I can see that the exit_function gets exectued successfully (when I do rmmod) but immediately after that the entire system freezes. With some other interrupt number (let's say 6) the system doesn't immediately freezes but eventually it does if I do cat /proc/interrupts/ or try to insert the driver again using insmod.

I know I should free the handler but I want to know where exactly the problem occurs if I don't free the handler.

Comment: So, you left a dangling pointer in the list of attached actions to the certain vIRQ. What do you expect? Any IRQ on the same line will follow dangling pointer and who-knows-what may happen after that.

Comment: Yes, a lot can go wrong. I agree. My task was to figure out the places where things can go wrong so to understand the kernel code and insides of kernel

Comment: I didn't get what you are talking about. The dangling pointer is ask for troubles. That's it. It's **already** wrong.